# Angular-Ckeditor Colour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, toolbar

I'm trying to add a custom toolbar into my Angular-Ckeditor toolbar.

Details:
angular: 1.5.8
angular-ckeditor : 1.0.3
ckeditor: 4.7.1

The angular-ckeditor has not been updated in 9 months and I suspect it just doesn't support coloured text and coloured backgrounds but I'm not sure.

This is how editorOptions are being set:

```
app.service('EditorOptions', function() {
 this.basic = {
 toolbar: [
      { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Undo', 'Redo' ] },
      { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
      { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'] },
      { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
      { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image',  'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar'] },
      '/',
      { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
      { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
      { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize'] }
  ]...
```

There is a script call from frontend:
    `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ckeditor/4.7.1/ckeditor.js"></script>`

In the controller:

```
$scope.editorOptions = angular.merge({}, EditorOptions.basic, {
              on: {
                blur: function() {
                    $scope.updateNode($scope.node);
                }
              }
            });
```

And then finally, the form:

```
    <textarea ckeditor="editorOptions" ng-model="node.body"></textarea>
```

Does anyone know why the toolbar configs for colour are not showing up? All of the other toolbar groups are rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

The fix: add the plugin

```
toolbarGroups: [
  { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
  { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
  { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
  //{ name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
  { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
  { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
  { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
  '/',
  { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
  { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
  { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'indent', 'list', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
  { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
  { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
  // { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
],
removeButtons: 'About,Source,Anchor,Cut,Copy,Paste,PasteText,PasteFromWord,Font',
format_tags: 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre',
removeDialogTabs: 'image:advanced;link:advanced',
linkShowTargetTab: false,
extraPlugins: 'colorbutton'
```